# Simple MahApps.Metro app not styling GroupBox

Tags: wpf, mahapps.metro

Here's the XAML of the test window:

```
<controls:MetroWindow x:Class="MahGroupBoxTest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:MahApps.Metro.Controls;assembly=MahApps.Metro"
             Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <controls:MetroWindow.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Colours.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Fonts.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Controls.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Accents/Blue.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Accents/BaseLight.xaml" />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>        
    </controls:MetroWindow.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <GroupBox Header="Test GroupBox" ></GroupBox>
    </Grid>
</controls:MetroWindow>
```

And here's the result:

[image]

I expected a styled `GroupBox` like in the demos. I've looked at the issues in the project and no one seems to have stumbled on this before. So I think the problem might be with me. Any ideas?

I'm building the project with .Net 4.0 and MahApps version is 0.10.0.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We discussed this on the GitHub forums:

https://github.com/MahApps/MahApps.Metro/issues/383

You can update to the pre-release project until I make time for another release.

> Install-Package MahApps.Metro -Pre